# Entity Framework - How to disable building the entire solution when enabling migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio

When use EF code first approach, I type 'enable-migrations' command in package manager console. It seems it will build the entire solution first. Is there a way to build the project containing dbcontext only (my dbcontext is in the DAL project)?

Comment: Isn't Code first meant to compile C# **first** then generate sql?

Comment: Agree with your point. But I don't want to compile every single project inside my solution. As I have a kentico web site project inside the solution, it took very long to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When enabling migration, it doesn't build the entire solution, but build the start-up project. By setting the start-up project to the project containing System.Data.Entity.DBContext objects, it will just build this project and its dependencies.